# How to identify if a value in column can be encoded to Latin in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, latin

My Postgres database encodes everything as UTF-8, but in a query when selecting a column I want to know if it can be encoded as Latin. I've no need to actually encode it as Latin but I need to know if can be encoded as Latin.

By Latin in mean what other people generally mean by Latin, i.e characters are recognisable to Western European speakers

i.e

```
SELECT val 
FROM 
TABLE1
WHERE IS_LATIN(Val);
```

**Solution**

I used the answer posted below, firstly I tried the python function but it failed because I dont have that language installed. Then I tried the pl/sql function and that failed because missing RETURN statement, but I fixed as follows and now works okay

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_latin(input text)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM convert_to(input, 'iso-8859-15');
  RETURN true;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN untranslatable_character THEN
    RETURN false;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to be more specific about "latin".

Assuming you mean ISO-8859-15, typical for Western europe

```
regress=> SELECT convert_to('a€bcáéíöâ', 'iso-8859-15');
      convert_to      
----------------------
 \x61a46263e1e9edf6e2
(1 row)
```

Beware, people often use `iso-8859-1`, but it doesn't support €.

However, you'll run into issues with currency symbols and other things that might typically appear in modern western european text. For example, ₽ isn't part of ISO-8859-15. Nor is ฿, ₡, ₹, and other major currencies. (Oddly, ¥ is in ISO-8859-15).

If you want to test without an error you'll need to either use PL/Python or similar, or use PL/PgSQL and trap the exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_latin(input text)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM convert_to(input, 'iso-8859-15');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN untranslatable_character THEN
    RETURN false;
END;
$$;

regress=> SELECT is_latin('฿');
 is_latin 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

That creates a savepoint on every call, though, which can get expensive. So perhaps PL/Python is better. This one makes an assumption about the `server_encoding` (assuming it is utf-8) which isn't wise, so it should really check that properly. Anyway:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_latin(input text)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE plpythonu
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
try:
    input.decode("utf-8").encode("iso-8859-1")
    return True
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    return False
$$;
```

Another option is to create a regular expression with a charset that matches all the chars you want to permit, but I suspect that'll be slow and ugly. Incomplete example:

```
SELECT 'ab฿cdé' ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9.áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚàè]*$'
```

... where you'd probably use the iso-8859-15 encoding table to produce the character list.

Comment: Thx, yeah Im a bit unsure about what i mean by latin. But like I said I dont need to convert it just know if it can be converted, how could i use convert as a check on a where clause like in the psuedo code Ive added

Comment: The calling code is pure SQL , I could create an install a function but I dont understand why/where the PL/SQL does a savepoint.

Comment: @PaulTaylor `BEGIN .. EXCEPTION` is an implicit savepoint. See the PostgreSQL documentation for PL/PgSQL control structures.

Comment: I need to check both iso-8859-15 and iso-8859-16 if it matches either then it should return true I tried modifying it but canot get it to work, could you help please ?